# Salt ldap.managed 'Tuple_to_LDAPMod' 'expected a tuple' issue

Tags: ldap, freebsd, salt-stack

I've got a new salt master on a fresh system and i'm verifying some of my pre-existing states.

I've got to the point where i'm now testing Salt's ability to update LDAP, and while it can connect successfully, it now appears to throw an error when trying to update a single value. I've stripped things back for testing and have the following:

sls:

```
ldapi-base:
  ldap.managed:
    - connect_spec:
        url: ldapi:///
        bind:
          method: simple
          dn: {{ salt['pillar.get']('ldapi-admin:admin') }}
          password: "{{ salt['pillar.get']('ldapi-admin:adminpw') }}"

    - entries:

      - dc=domain,dc=com: 
        - delete_others: True
        - replace: 
            objectClass: 
              - dcObject
              - organization
            dc: domain
```

Error message:

```
      ID: ldapi-base
Function: ldap.managed
  Result: False
 Comment: An exception occurred in this state: Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/var/tmp/.saltguru_c0a32f_salt/pyall/salt/state.py", line 1933, in call
              **cdata['kwargs'])
            File "/var/tmp/.saltguru_c0a32f_salt/pyall/salt/loader.py", line 1951, in wrapper
              return f(*args, **kwargs)
            File "/var/tmp/.saltguru_c0a32f_salt/pyall/salt/states/ldap.py", line 334, in managed
              __salt__['ldap3.add'](l, dn, n)
            File "/var/tmp/.saltguru_c0a32f_salt/pyall/salt/modules/ldap3.py", line 414, in add
              l.c.add_s(dn, modlist)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 428, in add_s
              return self.add_ext_s(dn,modlist,None,None)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 413, in add_ext_s
              msgid = self.add_ext(dn,modlist,serverctrls,clientctrls)
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 410, in add_ext
              return self._ldap_call(self._l.add_ext,dn,modlist,RequestControlTuples(serverctrls),RequestControlTuples(clientctrls))
            File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 313, in _ldap_call
              result = func(*args,**kwargs)
          TypeError: ('Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): expected a tuple', [('objectClass', [b'dcObject', b'organization']), ('dc', [b'domain'])])
 Started: 15:50:22.329045
Duration: 6.884 ms
 Changes:
```

I've been staring at it & tweaking it for ages, all to no avail. I thought it was a formatting issue at first, so various elements have been shuffled around and even removed. If I remove both dc & objectClass, the state passes successfully (but then, it doesn't actually do anything of course).

I've also been through several of the issues listed on Github, and investigated a few (#53232, #52022) and even updated (I was originally working with 2019.2.0). The system that I was originally using (now decommissioned) I believe was a 2018.x.y variant, but worked with no issues.

Can anyone offer any suggestions please? Far as I can tell from the sample output, it *looks* like a tuple..

salt --versions-report:

```
Salt Version:                                                                                                                                      
           Salt: 2019.2.2                                                                                                                          


Dependency Versions:                                                                                                                               
           cffi: 1.12.3                                                                                                                            
       cherrypy: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
       dateutil: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
      docker-py: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
          gitdb: 2.0.5                                                                                                                             
      gitpython: 2.1.11                                                                                                                            
          ioflo: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
         Jinja2: 2.10.1                                                                                                                            
        libgit2: 0.28.1                                                                                                                            
        libnacl: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
       M2Crypto: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
           Mako: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
 msgpack-python: 0.6.1                                                                                                                             
   mysql-python: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
      pycparser: 2.19                                                                                                                              
       pycrypto: 2.6.1                                                                                                                             
   pycryptodome: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
         pygit2: 0.28.0                                                                                                                            
         Python: 3.6.9 (default, Aug 22 2019, 01:16:05)                                                                                            
   python-gnupg: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
         PyYAML: 5.1                                                                                                                               
          PyZMQ: 18.1.0                                                                                                                            
           RAET: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
          smmap: 2.0.5                                                                                                                             
        timelib: Not Installed                                                                                                                     
        Tornado: 4.5.3                                                                                                                             
            ZMQ: 4.3.1                                                                                                                             


System Versions:                                                                                                                                   
           dist:                                                                                                                                   
         locale: US-ASCII                                                                                                                          
        machine: amd64                                                                                                                             
        release: 12.0-RELEASE                                                                                                                      
         system: FreeBSD                                                                                                                           
        version: Not Installed
```

Edit:

If I add the parameter `test=true` to the salt command, I get the following result:

```
      ID: ldapi-base
Function: ldap.managed
  Result: None
 Comment: Would change LDAP entries
 Started: 12:44:54.110453
Duration: 2.371 ms
 Changes:   
          ----------
          dc=domain,dc=com:
              ----------
              new:
                  ----------
                  dc:
                      - domain
                  o:
                      - myOrg
                  objectClass:
                      - dcObject
                      - organization
                      - top
              old:
                  None
```

It does look as though the salt side of things is okay, but whatever it passes to the next stage isn't?

And yes, the target box it is pointing at is also new, with no data in it.

Edit 2:

Tuple_to_LDAPMod appears to be a python-ldap function, based on [this link](https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/commit/e148184281c5d5e3bc98d4da95c913c495065374) to a commit, where I can find the error message i'm getting. The commit is to update the error message to something more meaningful.

Edit 3:

Updated py36-ldap from 3.1.0 to 3.2.0, no effect.

Edit 4:

Resurrected my old decommissioned master, Gentoo / Salt 2018.3.3 based. Had a couple of issues to sort, which upgraded Salt to 2018.3.4 (also tested 2019.2.2). Can replicate issue, so perhaps either target is the problem or there's something else going on. Considering raising it as an issue on SaltStack's Github

Edit 5:

Question posted to Salt-users Google Group (recommended next step).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with salt-stack but I see you are trying to update `dc=domain,dc=com` so that it uses objectClass `dcObject` and `organization`.

The (or one) issue is that [`organization`](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Organization) is a structural objectClass that requires the `o` attribute, so you need to specify it since `delete_others` is True.

```
  - dc=domain,dc=com: 
    - delete_others: True
    - replace: 
        objectClass: 
          - dcObject
          - organization
        dc: domain
        o: yourOrganization
```

You may also have to include `top` in objectClass if salt doesn't already by default.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The state I supplied above is a cut down one for testing, but my original (and still non-working state) does include an 'o' attribute.

I'm also interested in including 'top', shall go test that right now

Comment: Sorry, it was worth a try, but i'm still getting the same error. Albeit the error does now contain the new entries i've attempted to add

Comment: TypeError: ('Tuple_to_LDAPMod(): expected a tuple', [('dc', [b'domain']), ('o', [b'myOrg']), ('objectClass', [b'dcObject', b
'organization', b'top'])])

Comment: Yep , the error is not that clear so I would also try to put set `dc` as if it's a multivalued attribute (still with the same value but like objecclass)

Comment: Thanks Eric, that's also one I was sure I had tried, but it doesn't hurt to try again. Unfortunately it's the same error that comes up. I have an update to my question to add shortly too